# Remove my FTP passwords from phpDesigner 8

Tags: ftp, phpdesigner

I'd rather not have all of my FTP sites automatically connect when clicked.  Is there a way to force phpDesigner 8 to not store FTP passwords and force me to supply it each time I open a site?  I.e., for the duration of a session.  If my laptop decides to take a walk one day, there are a lot of sites that someone can access pretty easily.

SmartFTP has this feature - it will force a password entry when the connection is first attempted, then remember it until the connection is closed.  Looking for something similar.

The ideal solution lets me forget passwords on an individual basis per account (some are too cryptic to memorize, and I'm willing to risk keeping them remembered).

Comment: phpdesigner_ftp.xml contains this information, so you can remove it. Perhaps setup a shutdown script to delete or clean this file.

Comment: So not per-account?  I should have been more clear that I would prefer something through the IDE that I can't find, so that I could set each account individually.  (Some accounts have passwords that are too difficult to remember, so I would prefer to risk leaving them alone).

Comment: As you mentioned, it does not appear to be built into the IDE. You can create a default file with only the sites you want remembered and then copy this file over the current file every shutdown as a workaround.